How to merge 2 or more rows and SUM a column in an UPDATE without a primary key?
I have a table in SQL Server like this:



CTransaction
CQuantity
CItemCode
CUOM




001
2
0011
PACK


001
5
0011
PACK


001
1
0011
PACK


002
3
0011
PACK


002
3
0011
PACK



Basically this table contains item details with corresponding CTransaction. I want to merge and update rows with the same CTransaction and CItemCode while summing up their CQuantity.
After the update, as a result it would become something like the table below...



CTransaction
CQuantity
CItemCode
CUOM




001
8
0011
PACK


002
6
0011
PACK



I found a similar question in here, however the example includes a primary key. My table doesn't have a primary key and I have no idea how to do this. Is this even possible? What can I try next?
This would be easy if I was just going to SELECT the rows like this:
SELECT 
    CTransaction, SUM(CQuantity), CItemCode, CUOM 
FROM 
    Table 
GROUP BY 
    CTransaction, CItemCode, CUOM

But I don't want this. I want to update the table to actually remove the duplicates permanently.

If this is a one time thing, just create a new table and then use INSERT INTO ... followed by your select.

@TimBiegeleisen No I will be doing it periodically. I'm not sure what you mean by creating a new table and INSERT. Thank you.

Just create a view on top of this table.

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Every table should have a primary key. In this case the primary key should presumably be CTransaction, CItemCode, CUOM and you should fix the process to upsert this ongoing rather than add new duplicate rows.
It is possible to use MERGE for this though. One way is below (to update an arbitrary one per group and delete the rest).
WITH Tgt AS
(
SELECT *, 
        SumCQuantity = SUM(CQuantity) OVER (PARTITION BY CTransaction, CItemCode, CUOM ),
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CTransaction, CItemCode, CUOM  ORDER BY CTransaction) 
FROM YourTable
) 
Merge Tgt with (HOLDLOCK)
USING (VALUES(1)) src(rn) ON Tgt.rn = 1
WHEN MATCHED AND CQuantity IS DISTINCT FROM SumCQuantity THEN 
    UPDATE SET CQuantity = SumCQuantity 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
    DELETE;

Fiddle
Or another version provided by @Charlieface in the comments (that may be more efficient as avoids the common sub expression spool by only calculating the running sum - which can be done in a more streaming fashion as no need to add the calculated value back in to previous rows)
WITH target AS (
    SELECT *,
      SUM(t.CQuantity) OVER (PARTITION BY CTransaction, CItemCode ORDER BY CQuantity ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS TotalQty,
      LEAD(1) OVER (PARTITION BY CTransaction, CItemCode ORDER BY CQuantity) AS IsNotLast
    FROM YourTable t
)
MERGE target t
USING (VALUES(1)) AS v(dummy)
ON 1=1
WHEN MATCHED AND IsNotLast = 1 THEN DELETE
WHEN MATCHED AND CQuantity IS DISTINCT FROM TotalQty THEN
  UPDATE
    SET CQuantity = TotalQty;

Fiddle 2

I have no idea what you just did but it works like a charm. Thank you so much. I'm going to have to study each part of your SQL statement so I don't have to ask this type of question in the future. Thank you so much again.

@chris_techno25 - It uses windowed functions/aggregates to calculate the sum per group and to apply a sequential row numbering within each group. You can see the result of that here https://dbfiddle.uk/2yIceFym and the MERGE just updates the rows where the row number was 1 and deletes the rest (as these will be unwanted duplicates)

Given that you have stated that you might need to do this rollup periodically, it probably makes the most sense to create a view on top of your source table, using the aggregation query you already created:
CREATE VIEW yourView AS
SELECT CTransaction, CItemCode, CUOM, SUM(CQuantity)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CTransaction, CItemCode, CUOM;

Then just use SELECT * FROM yourView whenever you need to access this data.
